# Time complexity of find in DoubleLinkedList?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, time-complexity

First of all, I looked in the website to see if there was a post about that and I couldn't find any that answered my question.

In my classes of Algorithms and data Structures we were learning how to implement a Double Linked List. The teachers provided the code and a table with the time complexity of the each funcion. [Table with time complexity of the functions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slkz4.png)

Pior Caso means Worst Case
Melhor Caso means Best Case
Caso Esperado means Average Case

So my doubt is why is the Best Case time complexity of find O(1) and not O(n), the teachers say that I can't say that the best case is for n=1 but they also say that the best case is when the element we are looking for is the first. What do they mean by that??? Can someone explain to me how to calculate the best, worst and average case time complexity of algorithms?

here is the code for find:

[find algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jlJ6.png)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you have the following doubly linked list of numbers:

```
1 <-> 5 <-> 3 <-> 9 <-> 8 <-> 10
```

If you searched for the number `1`, beginning on the left, you would immediately find it.  This is an `O(1)` operation, because all you had to do was touch the first element (from the left).  On the other hand, if you were searching for the number `10`, and were so unfortunate as to also begin on the left, then you would have to touch *every* element in the linked list, all `N` of them (6 in this case).  This would be an `O(N)` operation.

In general, to find an element in a non-sorted linked list will require `N / 2` operations, meaning you need to on average search through half of the elements.  This is also an `O(N)` operation in the general case.